# pyqrcode ошибка

Tags: python, tkinter, qrcode

При использование вот этой команды

```
qr = pyqrcode.create(self.entry_name_standart.get(), self.entry_mark.get(), self.entry_polych.get(), self.entry_Adress.get(), self.entry_tel.get(), self.entry_ERDPOU.get())
            qr.png('qrtest', scale = 6)
```

Выбивает такую ошибку

> ```
> qr = pyqrcode.create(self.entry_name_standart.get(), self.entry_mark.get(), self.entry_polych.get(),
> ```
>
> self.entry_Adress.get(), self.entry_tel.get(),
> self.entry_ERDPOU.get())
> TypeError: create() takes from 1 to 5 positional arguments but 6 were given

С этим можно как то бороться(сохранить количество данных) ?

Так же при уменьшение количества позиций выходит такая ошибка

> ```
> TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил вопрос таким способом , просто добавил переменную qr2 и с нее уже считывал данные для генерации qr кода

```
def GenerateQR():
        qr2 = (self.entry_name_standart.get() + self.entry_mark.get() + self.entry_polych.get() + self.entry_Adress.get() + self.entry_tel.get() + self.entry_ERDPOU.get())


        qr = pyqrcode.create(qr2)
        qr.png('qrtest', scale = 6)
```